# Getting 400 error when trying to use Spotify recommendations with react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, spotify

I am getting 400 invalid request when trying to retrieve recommendations using the Spotify Web Api with react. I have made it retrieve the song I am playing, so I know the OAuth2 is working correctly.

The function for retrieving the recommendation is:

```
    // Scopes
    var scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email user-read-playback-state';

    // Function
    getRecommendations() {
        var data = {
            seed_tracks: [
                'spotify:track:3YSgPxT1T1HroVJxpN2aye',
                'spotify:track:2TxaEF8u2Po2c3RqevD3sd'
            ],
            seed_artists: [
                'spotify:artist:1p2z4hiBCkxfWZ6OvyGBSA',
                'spotify:artist:5SwsSD9zyWaWeVyK9qIW9l'
            ],
            seed_genres: [
                'classical',
                'country'
            ],
        };

        spotifyWebApi.getRecommendations(data).then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                nowPlaying: {
                    test: response.tracks,
                }
            })

        })
    }
```

any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was my input `'spotify:artist:1p2z4hiBCkxfWZ6OvyGBSA'` should only be `'1p2z4hiBCkxfWZ6OvyGBSA'` instead.